# PowerShell script to print all subfolders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a folder 'A' which as 2 subfolders 'A-1' & 'A-2'  and 'A-1' has 2 more sub folders 'A-1-1' and 'A-1-2' under it.

I would like to display all the folder names using powershell script.

```
   $folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\A -Directory
   foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    #For each folder in C:\banana, copy folder c:\copyme and its content to c:\banana\$folder
    #Copy-Item -Path "C:\copyme" -Destination "C:\banana\$($folder.name)" -Recurse
    write-host $folder
   }
```

My below script only prints :

```
A
A-1
A-2
```

I would like to print :

```
A
A-1
A-2
A-1-1
A-1-2
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try -recurse option like this :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\ -Directory -recurse
```

Comment: To have A included and above sample output better use `(Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\ -Directory -recurse).Name`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
 $Folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Folder\ -Directory -Name -Recurse

 foreach($Folder in $Folders)
 {
    $Folder = Split-Path -Path $Folder -Leaf

    Write-Host $Folder
 }
```